# Get Facebook taggable friends not using the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I need to show the list of the user friends. First, I check the friends who are using the app, and then the friends who are not (My app treat them in a different way).
Since the new API change, the only option is Taggable friends, but I need to separate the app user and the non app users.

I am looking for something like this:

```
 /v2.3/me/taggable_friends?filter=non_app_users
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what for do you need access to friends who dont use your app?

Comment: @luschn to tag them in a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get all friends with `me/taggable_friends` and match them with the list of friends you get with `/me/friends`, i don't think there is another way. But make sure you are using `taggable_friends` for tagging only, and nothing else.

Comment: Ok, I see. I was looking for a more "elegant" solution instead of merging lists. Thanks.